# Remove whitespace from field in awk

Tags: awk

I have a csv that I'm translating using an awk script.
One of the fields has white space that needs to be removed- however, the current function I am using is not working.

```
grnd_tack_number = gsub(/ /, "", $13)
```

input = 487     060210996314

desired output= 487060210996314

Current output = 5

Comment: From `awk` manual: The gsub() function returns the number of substitutions made. If the variable to search and alter (target) is omitted, then the entire input record ($0) is used. As in sub(), the characters ‘&’ and ‘\’ are special, and the third argument must be assignable.

Comment: Don't use the return value.  Your field `$13` would have the desired output after the `gsub` call.

Comment: No, you will not get that output given that input.

Comment: @EdMorton can you elaborate? which output you are referring to?

Comment: You only show one output - `5`. That's simply not the output you'll get from running gsub() on the input you posted, `487 060210996314`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest try to debug with this code sample.

```
{
    grnd_tack_number = $13;
    print grnd_tack_number;
    gsub(/ /, "", grnd_tack_number);
    print grnd_tack_number;
}
```